# Easy way to generate Maven dependencies in pom.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, dependencies

I'm new to Struts and Maven, converting a Dynamic Web Project to Maven.

Under the DWP I would just drag required JAR files into WEB-INF/lib but using Maven it looks like I have to add them to `pom.xml` using **groupId**, **artifactId** and **version**.

I have no idea what these fields are for any given JAR file and have been googling around to look this up, however some simple tutorials out there use 10, 20 or 30 different jar files.

Surely, there MUST be an easier - and saner, developer-friendly - way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those JARs are downloaded automatically from Maven Repositories, into your local repository (if they didn't exist there already).

e.g. http://mvnrepository.com/

The **groupId** is similar to a project prefix (e.g. `javax.servlet`), while the **artifactId** points to the JAR from that group (e.g. `servlet-api`). And the version is... well, the version of the JAR.

Say I want the Struts framework and API in my project. I quickly Google `maven struts`, and between the first results pops up [this link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/struts/struts). I pick a version, and then I look at the group and artifact id (which in this case are `struts` and `struts`).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

*You may find one or more implementations of the same framework, for example: from the group **org.apache.struts***

When your project requires a lot of JARs, then it is highly likely that some of those JAR automatically download their dependencies.

Add your struts dependency, and observe that it will automatically pull other required dependencies. In the end, you will have added about 5 JARs, tops. I can guarantee.